# How to write a Java method which escapes all the whitespaces, newline characters and comments?

Tags: java, text-parsing

I am trying to write a parser of a programming language and I need to escape all whitespaces, newlines and comments(of style /* and //) of a file and to stop just before the token. Assume that the file does not have any syntax error.

This is what I have tried, but I do not think it is the most simple solution. Any help is appreciated.

- `reader.charPrefetch()` gets one character but does not move the reading head in file
- `reader.charPrefetch(2)` gets the 2nd character counting from reading head

```
private void passCommentsAndWhitespaces(){
        char endOfFileChar = (char) 65535;
        String twoCharSeq = "" + reader.charPrefetch() + reader.charPrefetch(2);

        if(twoCharSeq.charAt(0) == endOfFileChar){
            return;
        }

        while (twoCharSeq.charAt(0) == ' ' || twoCharSeq.charAt(0) == '\n' ||
                twoCharSeq.equals("//") || twoCharSeq.equals("/*")){
            if(twoCharSeq.equals("/*")){
                twoCharSeq = "" + reader.readChar(3) + reader.charPrefetch();
                while (!twoCharSeq.equals("*/")){
                    twoCharSeq = "" + reader.readChar() + reader.charPrefetch();
                }
                reader.readChar();
            }else if(twoCharSeq.equals("//")){
                reader.readLine();
            }else {
                twoCharSeq = "" + reader.readChar() + reader.charPrefetch();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: By the way… https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR

Comment: Also consider [`StreamTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html).